# Android: SharedPreferences file doesn't create

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a SharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And I created a file xml called MyPREFERENCES which I put in the folder values, but the sharedpreferences doesn't work. Of course I write only the part of the code which created problems. How can I create the MyPREFERENCESf file?

Comment: SharedPreferences are not supposed to be stored in an XML file. A file named `MyPREFERENCES` (in your example) will be automatically created when you execute `getSharedPraferences`, but you don't access it directly from your code: you still do it through `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**`SharedPreferences`** are not not stored as an XML file... You can not access the file directly, (not of a way I know). These are stored on the storage and can be fetched by doing the same action that you specified. **Basically: The `SharedPreferences` file (e.g.MyPREFERENCES, as per your code) is automatically created in the storage the very first time it is called. You cannot access, edit or create this file directly**

**-Daniel**